# How to convert localDatetime to sql date time

Tags: java

I have a table with a DateTime column.
In java, I get localDatetime (now):

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(dtf.format(now));
```

i want to format this to sql Datetime to insert into MySQL.
Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You need to convert the `LocalDateTime` into milliseconds and create `java.sql.date` object from it, e.g.:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
long millis = now.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(0)).toEpochMilli();
Date date = new Date(millis);
```

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?

Comment: upvoted. but how to convert to sql datetime? That was OP's question. I guess that was why you were downvoted.